# Instalar create-react-app en un sub-dominio

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en React utiliza el comando [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). Tengo my servidor con NodeJS y quiero instalar el proyecto en el dominio principal como www.dominio.com (eso lo se hacer). Pero tambien quiero instalar una versión de pruebas en test.domonio.com. Es posible instalarlo en el sub-dominio y ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes colocar el contenido de la carpeta `/build` --después de ejecutar `npm run build`-, en la ruta que le asignes en el servidor o hosting al subdominio, de una manera similar a la que has desplegado en el dominio principal.
Salu2!